# Create alias based on input git commit

Tags: bash, zsh

I would like to create an alias to be added at the end of my zsh config file that allows me to commit files quickly to git.

Most of the times my commit command would look like:

`git commit -m "HO HO HO"`

And I was wondering if it is possible to make an alias that would be similar to the previous command but with this syntax:

`alias HO HO HO`

Where I only call the alias and captures the rest of text on the command as the commit message.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alias alone cannot do this. The problem is that you want to convert multiple arguments into a *single* argument for `git commit`. So you can define a function

```
foo () {
  git commit -m "$*"
}
```

and write

```
foo HO HO HO
```

However, I don't recommend doing something like this simply to save typing two quotes; provide a *single* argument yourself. Then you can define an alias

```
alias foo='git commit -m'

foo "HO HO HO"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you might set up git alias in your `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]
    c = "!f() { git commit -a -m \"$*\"; }; f"
```

Then you can type `git c Some commit message`.